# How can I rename or delete temporary filter views in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, delete, google-sheets-filter

This is specifically about **view-only sheets.**

This is specifically about **temporary** filter views.

When I create them (Data → Filter views → Create new temporary filter view) they have a name like "Temporary filter 1".  While viewing with this filter, the name is visible in the black bar, but cannot be edited from there, e.g. by clicking in the box the name is in; keystrokes seem to be swallowed.  I also see no other place to edit it.

I also see no place to delete it.  The X in the upper-right corner of the black bar seems to be the equivalent of Data → Filter views → None in that it just turns off the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary Filter Views can't be renamed.

To "delete" a a temporary Filter View, refresh the current web browser tab, open the spreadsheet in a new web browser tab or in another web browser